# Are there any ways to write VBA code to select autofilter field in range of another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code need to find the sheet name from column A and in same row it need to pick column E to filter data from another Woorkbook.

Can anyone please help me with this case.

```
Sub filter()
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fieldnum As Integer


Set wb = Workbooks("Quotes_Management_Tool tersrt")
 lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
fieldnum = wb.Sheets("QuoteExpiryDates").Range("E4:E" & lLastRow).Value
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$R$485").AutoFilter Field:=fieldnum, Criteria1:=RGB(198, _
        239, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

End Sub
```

I tried this but it unable to take the column value

Comment: `fieldnum = wb.Sheets("QuoteExpiryDates").Range("E4:E" & lLastRow).Value` This will give you an error as you have defined it as `Integer` but it will return a 2D array. What exactly are you trying there?

Comment: Also it is best to fully qualify the objects. Here `lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` the active sheet may not be the sheet you think is active. Update the question with more details. For example `**1.** I want to open "Quotes_Management_Tool tersrt" workbook. **2.** Then in Sheets "Blah Blah" in "Quotes_Management_Tool tersrt", I want to find the last row... and so on. Give as much details in the question. It will help us help you :)

Comment: I got two work books 1 is quotes and the another is comparision. from quotes workbook main sheets from col a it is splitting into seperates sheets in quotes workbook. after splliting to get data into splited sheets i need to get filtered data from comparision workbook. for that it need to check sheet and column number from quotes wb column a and e if there are multip[le names it just shoul go by column numbers to finter all the columns in comparision sheet.

Comment: i need to filter the data based on sheets name  in quotes work book by takeing column nuber  feom column e in quotes workbook and need to filter in comparision workbook that need to do till last value

Comment: Thats a good start. Can you update the question with this info? Comments are not permanent and this crucial info can be lost....